# Express JS session value undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, server

```
let createError = require("http-errors");
let express = require("express");
let path = require("path");
let cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
let logger = require("morgan");
const session = require("express-session");
let fileStore = require("session-file-store")(session);

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// Routers
let indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
let usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
let loginPage = require("./routes/login");

let app = express();

// System settings
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "SECRET_KEY_FOR_SESSION",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: oneDay, secure: !true },
    store: new fileStore(),
  })
);

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/login", loginPage);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

app.get("/createSession", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("This is sessionCreate file");
  let mysession = req.session.save;
  mysession.data = "LOGIN";
  res.end;
});
app.get("/getSession", (req, res, next) => {
  let getsession = req.session;
  res.send(`${getsession.data}`);
  res.end;
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

> **getsession.data ===  undefined?**

**I uploaded a variable to the session but it was not detected?**

All system settings are set correctly but what is the error? Session => The session is being saved to a storage folder but cannot be read.

[session_saved_folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muRVB.png)

Specifies the boolean value for the Secure Set-Cookie attribute. When truthy, the Secure attribute is set, otherwise it is not. By default, the Secure attribute is not set.

Note be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not send the cookie back to the server in the future if the browser does not have an HTTPS connection.

Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set. If you have your node.js behind a proxy and are using secure: true, you need to set "trust proxy" in express:

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your question.  These are common reasons that something you put in a session isn't still there on a future request: 1) The client is not preserving or sending the same session cookie from the prior request, 2) You are using some non-persistent session store and the Express server has been restarted, losing all prior session data, 3) Your modified session is not being properly saved in the session store after you added something to the session.  You can add logging to log the session cookie value to see if #1 is the problem.

Comment: FYI, `res.end;` all by itself is completely pointless - it does nothing.  You aren't calling the function.  And, in places you're using it, you don't call `res.end()` after you do `res.send()` because `res.send()` already ends the request for you.

Comment: Sessions are clearly saved but there is no way to access them again?

Comment: Express-session will access the session object on a future request if the incoming request contains the same session cookie.  Not sure what else you're asking?

Comment: Help solve the problem ... I didn't understand you?

Comment: What is your question?  I don't understand what you're asking for help with.

Comment: Give me a clear guide to the express session? (e. g. live example or documentation)

Comment: Here's the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session and that contains a link to the source code repository too.   FYI, this shouldn't be something that is hard to find if you have a basic understand of the nodejs ecosystem as you're already using a number of modules from the NPM system.

Comment: B1g th4nks! All super!

Comment: Well, if there's no real question here, then perhaps you can just delete your question now so it isn't just left hanging here with no answer.